# Moving column to left

Tags: tables, booktabs

I found this superb example in the latex wikibook.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{tabular}{llr}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          &    each     & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Being a complete LaTeX noob, I can't move Price column to the first column without breaking things. More specifically,  I want to move column Price to be the first column and yet preserving the location of column heading at the level of Animal and Description table headings.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor moving about of details...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l r }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
  \midrule
  Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
            & each        &  0.01      \\
  Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
  Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
  Armadillo & frozen      &  8.99      \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ r l l }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-3}
  Price (\$) & Animal    & Description \\
  \midrule
       13.65 & Gnat      & per gram    \\
        0.01 &           & each        \\
       92.50 & Gnu       & stuffed     \\
       33.33 & Emu       & stuffed     \\
        8.99 & Armadillo & frozen      \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Apart from moving around the actual column data, the heading movement of `Item` (as a `\multicolumn)` needs a `&` prepended to it so it spans columns 2-3 rather than 1-2.